# Android - Set ActionBar color across all Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How can I change the color of the ActionBar across all activities? For example, I set the actionbar color in my SettingsActivity, then want to apply that to my MainActivity.

I'm using this code to set the color:
`actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));`

I'm also trying to use SharedPreferences to do this, which I haven't found to work so far:
`prefs.edit().putInt("com.matt.cards.app", actionBarColor);`
And to get the ActionBarColor:
`int isActionBar = prefs.getInt("com.matt.cards.app", 0);`

I don't really know how SharedPrefs work, so can anyone guide me? Or show me another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `prefs.edit().commit()` after putting the color value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class that all your activity extends ... for example ...

```
public class MyActionBarActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.white_background)));
    }

}
```

Then let all of your custom activies extends this class like

```
public class Activity1 extends  MyActionBarActivity 

public class Activity2 extends  MyActionBarActivity 

public class Activity3 extends  MyActionBarActivity
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

try like this hope it will help you,

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">yourcolor</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: OP wants to pick the color from `SharedPreferences` at runtime.